# Format keywords in google docs with google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i'm trying to make a google app script for google docs that puts all the  occurrences of a string in a document in bold style, for example, for this text:

> hello
>
> hello
>
> good by
>
> 000000000000000000 hello 00000
>
> Hello hello hello
>
> 000000000000000001111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222233333333333333333444444444444444444444445555555555555 hello

If the string is `hello`, I would like the script to put it like this:

> **hello**
>
> **hello**
>
> good by
>
> 000000000000000000 **hello** 00000
>
> Hello **hello** **hello**
>
> 000000000000000001111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222233333333333333333444444444444444444444445555555555555 **hello**

I made this code:

```js
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();

  var Style = {};
  Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var found = body.findText("hola");

  while(found != null) {
    found.getElement().setAttributes(Style);
    found = body.findText("hello", found);
  }
```

But what I obtain after running the code, is this:

> **hello**
>
> **hello**
>
> good by
>
> **000000000000000000 hello 00000**
>
> **Hello hello hello**
>
> **000000000000000001111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222233333333333333333444444444444444444444445555555555555 hello**

So the code puts in bold all the line that contains the string `hello`, and not only the string `hello`

Somebody knows how could I do to put in bold only the string `hello` and not all the line that contains `hello`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the start and end of the text you are trying to edit by using getStartOffset() and getEndOffsetInclusive(). This will prevent your script to format the entire text block to **bold**. Please see below code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();

  var Style = {};
  Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var found = body.findText("hello");

  while(found != null) {
    var foundText = found.getElement().asText();
    var start = found.getStartOffset();
    var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    foundText.setAttributes(start, end, Style)
    found = body.findText("hello", found);
  }
}
```

Running this resulted to this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!